# Creating WPF popup   

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog, popup, wpf-positioning

I want to create a modal popup. So far I have made a window which I create when I need it. But I don't think that is the right way to do this. The problem is, everytime I call it, it opens about 20px to the right and 20px lower than previous one. It's annoying. Is this default behaviour or am I doing something wrong here?

```
Success win1 = new Success();
win1.ShowDialog();
```

Also, I want it to be centered if that's possible?

Comment: This is actually by design, and I don't see how it would annoy. This is covered by the Windows UX Guidelines: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511262.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below will center the your dialog box to the owner/parent form.

```
Success win1 = new Success();
win1.Owner = this; // For example , see the parent window here
win1.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
win1.ShowDialog();
```

Below are the alternative if you want to try. If you want to Center it to the screen use 'CenterScreen'

Manual - The startup location of a Window is set from code, or defers to the default Windows location.

CenterScreen - The startup location of a Window is the center of the screen that contains the mouse cursor.

CenterOwner - The startup location of a Window is the center of the Window that owns it, as specified by the Window.Owner property.

Answer (score 4):

You want to set the [WindowStartupLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstartuplocation.aspx) member of the Success window. Sounds like CenterOwner is the value you want.

Comment: I would note that you also have to set the Owner property in order for that to work.

Comment: I think I must be doing something wrong as this just centered to the whole screen, not my app.. Thanks anyway!